# How to execute a SOQL query in POSTMAN?

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to run the following SOQL query using POSTMAN but i am getting the following error. I have used the access token in the following statement.

SOQL Query:

https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+from+Account -H "Authorization:Bearer 00D90000000rBwy!  ARIAQB2opHNgIk3xbxx83k3letsZYb8siO2slRTDQAhlFsUV1ov_nkKOdxapsHkj8RYF5ZqRG7q1eGCynmdIqNAVdKwFNXDM"

**Error:**

> [
>       {
>           "message": "Session expired or invalid",
>           "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
>       } ]

I have the access token which i generated in the same session and used the same tab in Google Chrome.

[image]

But if i use the headers and specify the access token and content type in the headers then it worked correctly. Could someone please advice what is the issue in the first approach that is specifying the access token in the URL itself? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first format, using -H, is for a curl command line command. You wouldn't use that format in postman, because that will cause it to appear in the query string.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Can you please suggest a url format of executing SOQL in postman without specifying the headers separately?

Comment: @BaskaranS The headers are *required*, because is how authentication works in salesforce.com. The "-H" parameter in curl *also* produces a header, but since it's a command-line interface, you don't see it as such.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I understood now. Thanks again for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> But if i use the headers and specify the access token and content type in the headers then it worked correctly. Could someone please advice what is the issue in the first approach that is specifying the access token in the URL itself? Thanks.

There is no issue.  It is supposed to be in the header.

Comment: The OP is confusing documentation for postman and curl.